# Unable to FullPostBack using the GridView while Update Panel present in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Following Code while is pasted in page load for full post back

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btnnewSave);
```

this code worked properly and Now i Have another Linkbutton in Gridview 
When I try to use this code in row command for Full post back .unable to achieve the full post back (I used find control for the link button for Control ID)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I have seen that but here i am using the Row command , that solution was given based on the Row Data Bound

Comment: Once you register your control during RowDataBound, it will work as full post back control for you RowCommand

Comment: Sorry  i forgot to Mention, My grid view is in Datalist.

Comment: Sorry To Inform Like This , I have seen That Solution and it doesn't solve my problem . Please check this Question don't mark it as Duplicate. Once see this Scenario  . Thanks In Advance

Comment: A little bit more of information, like some extra relevant code, kind of task you want to do and kind of result you are expecting is needed here. It's difficult to determine possible cause of this behavior without seeing the code snippet you are working on.